# Should I move all my window air conditioners to the upper floor for better efficiency?

Tags: hvac

1800 sqft + basement

On main floor
2 window air conditioners 19k btu combined

Upstairs
1 5k btu air condition

There are 3 bedrooms upstairs. Does it make sense to just put all the ac units upstairs and let the cold air drop down through the floor or to drill vent holes in the floor? Would this method actually cool the main floor or reduce humidity on the main floor? The stairway is pretty open so all hot air floats up here pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Just as the hot air goes up since it is lighter the cold air will fall since it is heavier. If by chance you have a forced air heating system, you could run the furnace fan while the A/C units are on to help distribute and mix all the air in the house for better comfort. My son did this in his house for many years and it worked fine.